# Using array initializing notation on heap array

Tags: c, arrays, memory

What is the logical purpose behind preventing using array initializing notation (`{1,2,3...}`) on heap memory? It seems like functionality that would have been added to the standard by now...

Wouldn't it make sense if this was possible:

```
int *list;
list = malloc(sizeof(*list)*3);
*list = {1, 2, 3}; // error
```

But instead one must do this:

```
int *list;
list = malloc(sizeof(*list)*3);
list[0] = 1;
list[1] = 2;
list[2] = 3;
```

Am I missing something? Is there no easy way to pre-arrange an array?

Comment: Interesting question but if we know elements of array why use malloc, i think this isn't good way.

Comment: The problem is that C does not support array assignment due to Reasons™

Answer (score 1):

I would use compound literals along with `memcpy` to initialize.

```
memcpy(list,(int[]){1, 2, 3},3*sizeof(int)); // error
```

or simply without `malloc'`ing.

```
list = (int []){1,2,3};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just syntax.  You invented a [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) that is not included in standard language.

They wanted to keep the C language as simple as possible, contrary to the philosophy of other languages where they added a lot of syntax around the kernel.